# Using TFS 2015 Update 4, I am unable to "Create a new Build Definition" when I click the green plus sign.

Tags: tfs-2015, build-definition

Using TFS 2015 Update 4, 14.114.26403.0, I am unable to "Create a new Build Definition".

When I click the green plus sign or use the "Build Setup Now" button, the "Create New Build Definition" popup modal displays to select a build template. 
I select any template and click next, then I choose the "Default agent queue" and click the create button. The "Create New Build Definition" modal window closes and I am left on the "Build" page, but no build was created and nothing displays under the "Build Definitions".

I have the "Access Level" default set to "Advanced", and I have "Allow" permissions set for myself for my Project and Project Collection. I also have them set for all the TFS groups as defined.

I have googled every variation of this all day to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome, but also tried in IE.

Comment: Same result on Firefox

Comment: Access Level – Advanced (default) 
Security – I am in all the TFS groups, and my team membership has “Inherited Allow” or “Allow” for all permissions
Agent Pool – Default, with 1 agent idle in the pool

Preface -
After upgrading from TFS 2010 to 2015, fully configuring 1 database in a collection (automated & manual updates), I set the Access Level, defined an Agent and added it to the default Agent Pool. I then proceeded to create a Build Definition.

Comment: Scenario – 
1) From the “Build” page, where I clicked the green plus icon to display the "Create new build definition" modal popup window.
2)  From the “Create new build definition” modal “Select a template” view, I selected the “Visual Studio” template, and clicked the “Next” button. (I also tried all other templates)
3)  From the “Settings Repository Source” view of the modal, I select the “Default” agent queue, and click the blue “Create” button. 
4)  The “Create new build definition” modal window closes, but no new builds appear under the “All builds definitions”.

Comment: Event Viewer error - "No build task contributions were received while loading task definitions".

Comment: @DouglasBanks What about other users? Do they have the same issue? Have you tried to reboot the App Tier server? If not ,just try to reboot, clean caches for your client machine, or try with another client machine.

Comment: Yes, All users have this. We have cleared our cache and rebooted the server; Still no dice.

Comment: @DouglasBanks What about other projects? Seems the build tasks are invalid, if the TFS was upgrading from previous version, then you need to [Configure features after an upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade)

Answer (score 1):

Mystery Solved!! In TFS 2015 Update 4, there is a requirement to have HTTP Verb "OPTIONS" set to "Allowed" in IIS. By default the "OPTIONS" verb is set to "Disallow" to prevent users from finding out the settings on your web site. The TFS Build Definitions process needs this verb to function. Prior version of TFS did not use this verb. I still do not understand why the TFS Update 4 installation did not flip this on because I installed TFS well after IIS was installed. Anyway, I hope this helps the next unfortunate soul that stumbles upon this before they lose their hair... :)